# select all ids which has flag x1 but not x2 in same column

Tags: mysql

From a table which has 2 columns ID and Flag

```
ID  Flag
111  2
222  2
333  2
444  2
333  5
111  5
```

I want to select all id which have 2 flag but not 5

expected answer

```
222
444
```

I tried below but that won't work.

```
SELECT * from table
where flag in ('2')
and flag not in ('5')
```

Comment: Why make a complicated SQL when simple SQL statement would do the job? You haven't mentioned the datatype of Attribute `flag`. It is presumed that it is not a Number, so please try `SELECT * from table WHERE flag = '2';`. If the `flag` is of Numerical datatype, then skip the `'` in `='2'`.

Comment: @Raky that would return 111 and 333 which I don't want to include in the output.

Comment: No, it will list all id and flag where flag is 2. so the result will be 111,222,333, 444 . The last two records will be omitted in the result. Try it out. Your aim isn't clear? You asked for listing all records with attribute flag having value 2 but you do not want to list certain attribute id with flag value 2.

Comment: *I tried below but that won't work.* Of course. Both conditions in WHERE are checked in the same row. And another rows not affected on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id
FROM source
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(flag=2)
   AND !SUM(flag=5)
```